# Entity Framework OnModelCreating duplicate tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2 and EF code first creates 5 tables

> dbo.AspNetRole
>
> dbo.AspNetUsers
>
> dbo.AspNetUsersClaim
>
> dbo.AspNetUsersLogin
>
> dbo.AspNetUsersRole

I need to change names, so I used this piece of code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("RepricerUsers", "miportal");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("RepricerUsersClaim", "miportal");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("RepricerUsersLogin", "miportal");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("RepricerUsersRole", "miportal");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("RepricerRole", "miportal");
}
```

It works but the table created from `IdentityUser` is duplicated, so I found both `dbo.AspNetUsers` and `miportal.RepricerUser`.

[image]

Why this is this table duplicated? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problem.you can't change the aspIdentity table name directly so you should do it with a class that inherit from IdentityUser class.here is what I have done in one of my project.you can change the class names to whatever you want.
**Model**

```
  public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Address { get; set;}//it can be any propery or you can leave class empty
}
```

**Config class**

```
 public sealed class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        ToTable("RepricerUsers", "miportal");
    }
}
```

then in you context class

```
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfig());
    }
```

Comment: your answer is right, I end up with a slightly different solution.
I added `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("RepricerUsers", "miportal");` where `ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser`, so that both write on the same table

Comment: Your aproach is good.I needed to change ApplicationUser to User for some reasons.there is no difference, both adress the problem